# How can I get a selected item from a Linq query in a variable

Tags: winforms, linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0

When I Select Employee Name in a combobox, I need  to display Employee BirthDate in a textBox

```
using (LINQtoEntitiesEntities MyEntities = new LINQtoEntitiesEntities())
{
    ObjectQuery<Employee> Emp = MyEntities.Employee;
    comboBox1.DataSource = (from u in Emp select new { u.ID, u.Name, u.BirthDate }).ToList();
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "ID";
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
    TextBox1.Text = ....................... ;
}
```

I need to get `u.BirthDate` in a variable from the query
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 4):

To Add it right off the bat try:

```
var employees = (from u in Emp select new { u.ID, u.Name, u.BirthDate }).ToList();
comboBox1.DataSource = employees;

if(employees.Any()) 
    TextBox1.Text = employees.First(x => x.BirthDate);
```

To Dynamically change it when you change the combobox, you could add the following event handler to your SelectionChangeCommitted event:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox senderComboBox = (ComboBox) sender;

    var selectedObject = senderComboBox.SelectedItem;

    if(selectedObject == null) return;

    TextBox1.Text = ((IEnumerable<Employee>)senderComboBox.DataSource)
                        .First(emp => emp.ID == senderComboBox.Value).BirthDate;

}
```

(Assumes Birthdate is a string already);

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
TextBox1.Text = ((IEnumerable<Employee>)comboBox1.DataSource)
    .Where(e => e.ID == comboBox1.Value)
    .First().BirthDate;
```